# How to tell typescript the type of a key inside a nested loop which depends on the key before?

Tags: typescript

I have nested loop (playground link below):

```
    const foo: tFoo = Foo.getEmptyFooObject();

    // will be 'foo1' | 'foo2' | 'foo3'
    let firstDimensionKey: keyof typeof foo;
    for (firstDimensionKey in foo){
      const firstDimensionValues = foo[firstDimensionKey];

      // secondDimensionKey is never. Because typescript doesnt know what the firstDimensionValues is at this moment.
      // How can I make typescript know what it should be?
      let secondDimensionKey: keyof typeof firstDimensionValues;
      for (secondDimensionKey in firstDimensionValues) {
        // is there a away to avoid casting (firstDimensionKey + '-' + secondDimensionKey) as tFooFlattenedKeys?
        foo[firstDimensionKey][secondDimensionKey] = this.getValueOfFoo((firstDimensionKey + '-' + secondDimensionKey) as tFooFlattenedKeys);
      }
    }
```

The secondDimensionkey is never because it depends on the values firstDimensionValues holds. At least I think so.

Is is possible to let typescript know which key it is at the moment? Maybe with a conditional or mapped type? Currently we loop over every key on its own, having 10+ loops inside the function. This seems to be stupid (see playground last function: toObjectIWantToAvoid).

##### Edit: Type any is not allowed

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBMBiD29YBsCGxgQHYQCYGkIQBnKAXigAMAzRARgFoASAbwGsj5qYF4BtAOS14dAQF0AvpSgAfKsIBMzdp25xEgxeKmz5iAMzKOILjw1CD2ygG4AsAChQkM-HJQWDqFGF0AXO88vb3oAI1QAJz8oLABXAFsQiHCZYmBwgEssAHMAGkCvHzDwhX9YhKSUtMzc-OCRIv1S+MTk1IzsvPsvCU6CxBKArqDFIqiylsr2mqG++AUigfGKture4f6GpvLWqo7akYiAFi2Jlb2hnsDhRsGguv1Rk+Xd6bvrhaedqbWJBwk7ewOADGaGIpF4tygAHood40BhsHgoLh0KhvOF4HEoED4Fg2jEgcB4OFAmAMgA3dDQcIQVC4XHIEB1ABCEQAsqgwP4WHxjFBMi4UOhMDgCERiGJ-GcsjIluEJG4PDMghYRAxChFRP46Gs7qrGBrigJ-AJiJiIMAABbVAS6lU+dWhCL6Y1QAS22peVVKA6RV3uu1exSOuYLf0e5VB-oh+bO110BSBt3B32HcNJ1WGd6a10ABgz1xDDwiCn9uYj3QBpJiIWQ6SB2Nx+MJxIAFMIACKo-zqeAASkhXhhcOF2FIVugndR-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-RLNwcOT9ykpSJKBgB1QHgAAFXgABBdXNZfHTEHUpstMQIfXD0xADPPS9r0QZuLPr5V8YQyPiHJ-bKbihLp58Uvgg5nx14mwW9-oCXgOEZd6Fa+gT6IEOKDDmfgEj6PY9bfVU7N4+7sa7O8tc6IHziJV2xcD4VzuKvRQD8opbxMGoNau94A3zmAfdm+t+hwNytfRQl80J4P6HfOYcCn7zkeq-d+MdEBx29D-dCcCc5O1HIXcUJdy7L2gX5a4cCKaIKpigtB+gMHEiwfAfQOCz6oOuAQ2i58JEkMkf-Dej9Q4Liof-D+tCv6FktvcJhQCWEFzwEXDhyooFBCrr+OorNLG7nkg2COWiaHwAoK2YwE9QEuzMZ8SYesyAAD4KFLhXOyTkvJH4AgkEAA)

Comment: Eh, this sort of nested correlated typing isn't going to be handled very well by the compiler no matter what you do.  You're already doing unsafe things (`as TFooFlattenedKeys` and `getValueOfFoo()` returns `string | number` which is not known to be assignable to `foo[k][k2]`) so you might as well just give `foo` the type `any` and be careful.  If you really want you can refactor to use generics to get types like `TFoo[K][K2]` but they don't really make anything safer.  See [this code](//tsplay.dev/wX7AoW) for both approaches.  Let me know if you want me to write up an answer with any of this.

Comment: Thanks for point me at the typo. I pretty sure I already corrected that yesterday... Anyway: I am not allowed to use any.  What do you think about the "many loops" solution like the toObjectIWantToAvoid function? It should be safe but ugly imo.

Comment: Generally for correlated things like this your choices are "safe but redundant" or "terse but somewhat unsafe", so it's up to you which is more important.  If you are not allowed to use `any` and your acceptance of an answer depends on that, you should probably specify it in the question. You can avoid `any` if you must... [for example](https://tsplay.dev/NdjMXW).  So do you want me to write up an answer here or am I missing something?

Comment: I will take your solution to our meeting but I guess the unknown will be a problem there. ESLint will probably complain. But feel free to write an answer and I will accept it. Your first comment told me everything I was afraid of...